# How to do beforeAll in Swift Quick Nimble

Tags: swift, jasmine, xcode-ui-testing, quick-nimble

In Jasmine, the beforeAll() block can be used within a describe and run before all of the it blocks within that describe.  Is there something equivalent to this in the Quick/Nimble BDD framework in XCUITest (xcode) in Swift?  I could only find the beforeSuite() but that is ran before all describe blocks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, [Quick](https://github.com/Quick/Quick) does not support `beforeAll` / `afterAll`.

You can read more on the reasons behind this decision in this [issue](https://github.com/Quick/Quick/issues/161#issuecomment-60042470). But the short answer is **it is not currently supported and they have no plans to add them** in the near future.

You should be able to go around this using the other options supported: `beforeSuite`, `afterSuite`, `beforeEach` and `afterEach`.